# Black Screen on Windows 10 Boot, then loads after disk check

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

Recently my Windows 10 startup has been acting strangely.  Sometimes (not all the time) when turned on, it will show the BIOS screen, show the Windows activity symbol, then black screen.  If left alone, after a minute or two it will eventually show the BIOS screen again, then start a disk check.  After this, Windows will load correctly (shows the login screen).  Any idea of why this might happen?

Other things: I am on a desktop, and I had GRUB installed a while ago, but it hasn't had this problem until recently.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Windows is performing a disk check - meaning your drive has bad sectors, Windows is fixing it, than reboot and starting.

I would turn on S.M.A.R.T. reporting (inside BIOS) - that should provide you with a verification for the health of your drive....

It could be caused by some SW, but most likely you are facing a HW failure

Comment: Would SMART work for SSD's? (thats what Windows is booting off of)

Comment: Yes, they would - see https://serverfault.com/questions/10326/do-ssds-support-smart

Comment: I wasn't able to find this in my BIOS (Gigabyte H-170 if that helps).  Is this something that should be loaded via software/windows?